# Как исправить ошибку при записи в БД (связанные таблицы)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Проект на python 3.6 + django 2.0 + rest_framework.
База данных - sqlite3.

В проекте 2 связанные модели (соответственно 2 связанные таблицы в базе): Event (встречи) + Place (места, где пройдут встречи).
В таблице Event есть поле place - оно должно содержать id из таблицы Place.

Код из файла models.py:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    title_p = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type_p = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    adress_p = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link_p = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title_p',)

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)
```

Код из serializers.py:

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = ('id', 'title_p', 'type_p', 'adress_p', 'link_p')

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    place = PlaceSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'place', 'link', 'date', 'time')
```

С таким подходом получается GET-ом вывести данные из таблицы Event (c вложенными значениями из таблицы Place):

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Встреча1",
    "description": "Описание1",
    "price": "100",
    "place": {
        "id": 1,
        "title_p": "Место1",
        "type_p": "ТипМеста1",
        "adress_p": "Адрес1",
        "link_p": "http://vk.com/111/"
    },
    "link": "http://vk.com/11111/",
    "date": null,
    "time": "23:00:00"
}
```

Но если попытаемся добавить в Event новую запись (например через httpie), появляется ошибка:

```
http -a admin:???????? POST http://localhost:8000/events/ title=Встреча2 description=Описание2 price=200 place=1 link=http://vk.com/22222/ date=2018-01-23 time=23:00


Exception Type: IntegrityError at /events/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: events_event.place_id
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

У вас в EventSerializer указано явно:

`place = PlaceSerializer(read_only=True)` - Только для чтения

Тут вам надо решить, будет ли при создании Event создаваться также Place, или же вы будете манипулировать уже созданными заранее Place.

Если брать второй вариант, то я бы сделал второй сериалайзер для добавления нового Event:

```
class EventCreateOrUpdateSerializer:
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'place', 'link', 'date', 'time')
```

В данном случае поле place будет использовать PrimaryKeyRelatedField (если я не ошибаюсь, но в любом случае можно и явно указать), и можно будет в него передавать при создании/редактировании primary key какого-либо уже созданного Place.

Если же вас интересует вложенное создание/редактирование, то можно убрать аргумент read_only=True и переопределить метод create (update) у EventSerializer:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    place = PlaceSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'place', 'link', 'date', 'time')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        place_data = validated_data.pop('place')
        place = Place.objects.create(**place_data)
        event = Event.objects.create(place=place, **validated_data)
        return event
```

Можно вместо явного создания также использовать PlaceSerializer, если честно, я не знаю какой подход лучше. В любом случае, лучше избегать варианта с вложенными writable сериалайзерами (хотя бы наоборот - Place создается с одним или несколькими Event, связь один-ко-многим все таки) так как это достаточно сильно расходится с REST.

PrimaryKeyRelatedField, там же найдете много информации по полям для связанных моделей:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Документация по вложенным сериалайзерам:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут в документации описана проблема связаных моделей. Они по умолчанию всегда read_only.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Но если вы хотите передать id уже существующей записи то вот небольшой трюк как можно ето сделать в сериализаторе .

```
class VisitorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagsSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    tags_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, required=False, write_only=True,
                                                 queryset=Tag.objects.all(), source='tags')

    class Meta:
        model = Visitor
        fields = '__all__'
```

Я добавил поле tags_id Которое доступно только при записи, и тогда с фронтенда я присылаю **`tag_id=3`** и у меня связь создается по **id** но в ответ (и на GET) я получаю **полную модель**.
Мне етот вариант нравится больше так как я написал одну строчку а не создавал новый сериализатор для етого. Компактней и удобней)